# Pair Edifier TWS x3 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I've had my JBL BT400 headphones working on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop for quite a long time without any problems: turn bluetooth on, turn the headphones on, pair and be happy.

I've had to lend the headphone and got myself the TWS x3 earbuds from Edifier. My phone could identify and pair with them, no problems, but when I try with my laptop,for some unknown reason, the system couldn't see them. Thing is I've got no idea what could be the problem, since the Bluetooth works just fine with the headphones.

So, could anybody help me pair and use the new earbuds?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [instructions](https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/bluetooth-headphones-ubuntu/). If that doesn't work:

1. Turn off laptop's Bluetooth
2. Take off the earphones from case
3. Turn on your Bluetooth, try to search
4. In the booklet manual, pairing needs to hold the touch for 1-3 seconds. Do this while searching. Red and blue lights flashes rapidly.

**Note**: you don't have to follow `steps 1-3`, I just added it cause I saw some posts here where they fixed it by turning it on/off in that specific order. I'm using Ubuntu 21.04 (hirsute), 5.56 BlueZ (`dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'`) and shows bluetooth modules (`pactl list | grep -i bluetooth`)